# In-app "Quick Actions" for 3D Touch

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, 3dtouch, swift4

In iOS 11 and in Swift, how can I display 3D Touch "quick actions" like those on the Home screen (curved menu items and blurred background except for selected element), but inside my app?

See this screenshot of the Phone app for reference.:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/3d-touch-tutorial/)

Comment: @chirag90 I have actually read this tutorial before, but it doesn’t answer my question. I’m still looking into the answer below.

Comment: @Wilsonator5000 Did the answer below worked as you expected. I meant could you make a preview screen with just only the actions?

Comment: @Varun I actually ended up using a library called [ActionsList](https://github.com/LowKostKustomz/ActionsList) that was suggested in an answer below, but it seems like the answer was deleted. I'll look into your solution in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation on in-app peek & pop. There's a "ViewControllerPreviews" sample mentioned at the top that you can download.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/